# The use of "@#" in dynare/Matlab

Tags: matlab, economics

I'm trying to handle the Zero Lower Bound in a DSGE model in dynare(a package for Matlab). I found a paper that developed an algorithm for stochastic simulations at the ZLB, and I found some of the author's code, but I can not interpret part of the code. I've looked everywhere for an answer. This is what the code looks like:

```
@#define TShadow = 30   
@#define TIRF = 15    
@#define TSimul = 300   
@#define TDrop = 100    

@#if TShadow > TIRF
    @#define TInitIRF = TShadow
@#else
    @#define TInitIRF = TIRF
@#endif

var pi, y, i, shock_pi, shock_nu, shock_i;
varexo epsilon_pi, epsilon_nu, epsilon_i;
```

The use of @# is so mysterious and I cannot find a single usage of it. I have run the code and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the [Macro-processing language](http://www.dynare.org/manual/index_30.html) syntax. This link discusses expressions, directives, typical usages, and compares MATLAB/Octave loops versus macro-processor loops. See more regarding  Dynare macro-processor syntax and typical usages in this [pdf](http://www.dynare.org/sebastien/2012-dynare-macroprocessor.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the code with Dynare's `savemacro` command line option, e.g.

`dynare mymodel.mod savemacro=final_mod_file.txt onlymacro nolinemacro`

This will write the regular readable Dynare model code that the preprocessor creates after resolving the macro language commands to the `final_mod_file.txt` file. See the Dynare manual for more details on the command line options.